# How to stop my macro from triggering another one -VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have some code that triggers a UserForm to show based on a cell value. I have a second VBA module that on a button click moves rows to different sheets based on a cell value in the same aforementioned column. Below is the code to show the UserForm. My code to move rows across sheet also triggers this UserForm to show when column 17 is listed as "Follow-Up". Does anyone know of a way around this, to help prevent the UserForm from showing when moving rows. The idea is to only have the UserForm to show up when "Follow-Up" is selected from the drop down list in the column. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 17 And Target.Value = "Follow-Up" Then UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = false` in the macro that copies rows?

Comment: Make sure to turn it back on after.